# Customise cron job

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, bpmn-engine

I would like to repeat the entire flow from the service tasks Fetch,Store S4tXml, Process Individual order json… till the end for multiple Id’s. How can I adapt the above camunda model without messing up the process variables? does multi instance work?
for exaple
for(var i =0 ; i<n;i++){
Fetch,Store S4tXml, Process Individual order json…
}

[image]